# Bash: dirname not working with xargs

Tags: bash, shell

The following command:

```
echo ./test/test2/test23 | xargs -I "{}" echo `dirname "{}"`
```

Outputs: `.` (not as expected)

The following command:

```
echo ./test/test2/test23 | xargs -I "{}" echo `dirname ./test/test2/test23`
```

Outputs: `./test/test2` (as expected)

The following command:

```
echo ./test/test2/test23 | xargs -I "{}" echo `echo "{}"`
```

Outputs: `./test/test2/test23` (as expected)

Why is the first command not outputting `./test/test2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the unexpected output is that the subshell substitution of `dirname "{}"` is being executed first (having an output of `.`), making the command effectively `echo "./test/test2/test23" | xargs -I "{}" echo .`.  Since there is no match for `xargs`' specified marker of `{}`, there is nothing replaced, and `echo .` runs as expected, with output of `.`.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you have a suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: `echo "./test/test2/test23" | xargs -I "{}" dirname "{}"` seems to have the intended result.

Comment: ah yep, fair. I'm trying to solve this problem: find . -name "*" -type f | xargs -I "{}" cp "{}" \`dirname "{}"\`. Would you be able to help me find an equivalent to this please?

Comment: That would be beyond the scope of this question, but if you were to submit a new question with your needs explained, I'm confident it will get addressed.

Comment: Sure, here's a link to the new question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736560/nested-command-inside-xargs