# Nested command inside xargs

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder of folders of folders of files. I'm trying to copy all the files to their parent.
The following command doesn't work because `dirname "{}"` executes before the find command. What could be done instead please?

```
find . -name "*" -type f | xargs -I "{}" cp "{}" `dirname "{}"`
```

Comment: To be clear, the intent is to move all files into their parent directory?  What is the intent if there are duplicate filenames?

Comment: @DopeGhoti That will never happen in my situation. If it does for whatever reason, the files with the same name should be identical so it is fine if they overwrite each other.

Comment: Do you want move or copy? Your question says copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move all files from the directory tree descending from the current working directory into each file's parent directory, you don't even need to break out `xargs` or `dirname`; `find` can do this for you:

```
$ tree
.
+--- dir1
|   +--- somefile
+--- dir2
|   +--- someotherfile
$ find . -type f -execdir mv "{}" ../ \;
$ tree
.
+--- dir1
+--- dir2
+--- somefile
+--- someotherfile
```

The `execdir` option for `find` will execute the specified command in the directory in which each matching file is found.

Comment: Works flawlessly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solving the XY-problem by DopeGhoti, I wanna give an answer to the actual question, as imho it is also good to know: surround the cp command with another shell.

```bash
find . -type f | xargs -I "{}" sh -c 'cp "{}" `dirname "{}"`'
```

As this does not work tho (because the cp command would try to copy the files into the directory where they already are, you would need to append a /.. like this:

```bash
find . -type f | xargs -I "{}" sh -c 'cp "{}" `dirname "{}"`/..'
```